# No such file or directory on node shell script

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, shell, ubuntu

I have a script `hello` which has the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log('hello there!');
```

When I run it with `./hello`, I get the following output:

```
$ ./hello 
: No such file or directory
```

When I run it with `node ./hello`, I get the following output:

```
$ ./hello 
hello there!
```

This is on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. (just tried, worked)

Comment: Did you run chmod +x hello ?

Comment: @JamesMonger you should have added , for which OS you are trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by setting the correct permissions with `chmod +x hello` and ensuring that the line endings were correct.